# SSJS updateDE returns null

Tags: ssjs

According to the documentation updateDE should return the number of rows modified

```
<script runat="server">
var rows = Platform.Function.UpdateDE("CustomerData",["Company","Country","Region"],["exampleCompany","USA","West"]);
```

However it seems to always return null? However checking in the DE the field has been updated.

Comment: I'm afraid you're correct, I have never seen the amount of rows affected being returned..

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss something in documentation. [link for reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatede.htm)

Note: `UpdateDE : It don't returns value`.

As mentioned in documentation :

> **UpdateDE**
>   Updates an existing row in a data extension for the specified number of columns used to build the where clause listed in name value pairs followed by a list of columns to be updated in name value pairs.Returns no value.Use this function with email messages at send time only.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> UpdateDE(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> ```
>
> **Function Properties**
>
> 1. string
>      Required
>      Name of data extension from which to update the specified row
> 2. numeric
>      Required
>      Number of columns used to build WHERE clause
> 3. string
>      Required
>      Column name to build WHERE clause
> 4. string
>      Required
>      Value used to build WHERE clause
> 5. string
>      Required
>      Column name to build INSERT clause
> 6. string
>      Required
>      Value used to build INSERT clause
>
> **Usage**
>
> ```
> UpdateDE('SendDE',1,'_SubscriberKey',_SubscriberKey,'DateSent',NOW())
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old but for the record:

@Kumar Akhil
Your answer is based off the AMPScript function not the SSJS as asked by M4rcster.

SSJS is suppose to return the number of rows modified as per SSJS documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpdateDE.htm)

> Updates existing information into a data extension as indicated by the
>   array containing the listed column name and value pairs. You can
>   include multiple column name and value parts in a single call. You can
>   use this method in sendable contexts, such as email messages. This
>   call returns the number of rows modified.

However, as the comment by Christopher states, this seems not to work. Either the documentation is wrong OR the method is not working as intended.